# How to update AWS lambda docker container version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

My intension is to deploy a new container version to my AWS lambda.
Lambda now offers docker run time and I have successfully updated the lambda docker container from the web console but not able to do so from the cli.
There is an update-function

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html

But it does not show how I can update the container image version.
Is it possible to do update the container version via the aws cli?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use [update-function-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html), not `update-function-configuration`.

Use the `--image-uri` option, and note that Lambda references image versions via their SHA, not the tag.

Comment: How do I know what the updated sha will be after I deploy? I just deploy with the ecr url + image tag, so this seems difficult to update lambda functions.

Comment: @ArielFrischer - if you use a unique tag for each image, then it's not a problem: Lambda will see that it doesn't have the tag and attempt to retrieve it. Where you'll run into problems is if you use `latest`: it will not attempt to retrieve on each run (this is just like `docker run`).

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine with docker tags, thanks for the heads up about the `latest` tag.

Comment: How do you add the sha to the image URI?

Comment: It is possible to use tag or digest hash with `--image-uri` e.g.
*Tag:* `aws lambda update-function-code --image-uri <account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repo_name>:latest`
*Digest:* `aws lambda update-function-code --image-uri <account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repo_name>@sha56:<sha>`

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the other comments, a Lambda function won't automatically use an image with `latest` tag pushed to ECR but running the `update-function-code` will pick up the new image tagged `latest` from ECR.

Comment: @Parsifal please write the whole command out, it makes it a lot easier to grok. Like what Cas did.